# BuildFire Custom Tabs Not Loadings

Tags: buildfire

I am trying to add custom tabs into my app. My plugin.json for the custom tabs as the following:
[image]

And my file structure looks as such:

[image]

But each time I navigate to a page, I get this error:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you added both index.html files to the build bundle?

Comment: That was it! and it works now

Answer (score 3):

As Mas pointed out, it has to be added to the webpack.confg.js is two locations:

In the entry:

```
entry: {
    'control/content/content': [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/content/index.js')
    ],
    'control/design/design': [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/design/index.js')
    ],
    'control/settings/settings': [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/settings/index.js')
    ],
    'control/security/security': [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/security/index.js')
    ],
    'control/user/user': [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/user/index.js')
    ],
    'widget/widget': [path.join(__dirname, 'src/widget/index.js')]
  },
```

And the plugins:

```
WebpackConfig.plugins.push(
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'control/content/index.html',
    minify: { removeComments: true, collapseWhitespace: true },
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/content/index.html'),
    chunks: ['control/content/content']
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'control/design/index.html',
    minify: { removeComments: true, collapseWhitespace: true },
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/design/index.html'),
    chunks: ['control/design/design']
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'control/settings/index.html',
    minify: { removeComments: true, collapseWhitespace: true },
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/settings/index.html'),
    chunks: ['control/settings/settings']
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'control/security/index.html',
    minify: { removeComments: true, collapseWhitespace: true },
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/security/index.html'),
    chunks: ['control/security/security']
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'control/user/index.html',
    minify: { removeComments: true, collapseWhitespace: true },
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/control/user/index.html'),
    chunks: ['control/user/user']
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'widget/index.html',
    minify: { removeComments: true, collapseWhitespace: true },
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/widget/index.html'),
    chunks: ['widget/widget']
  })
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution, can you please accept your answer so it gets visible to others?